# How do I use the Elysium Project?

Tags: c#, wpf, themes, expression-blend

The [Elysium](http://elysium.codeplex.com/) project on CodePlex looks interesting. One problem. I can't figure out how to use it. I can only assume that there is an assumption that the user knows what he or she is doing. I don't apparently. I download the Debug Binary from [here](http://elysium.codeplex.com/releases/view/82202). It has a batch file for loading the files, and it looks to have run without error. But I can't figure out where to go from here. When I open Blend, I see no templates or themes. Can someone please help?

Thanks

Comment: So you want us to study it and summarize what you should do?

Comment: No, I want to know how to at least start a project using it. Currently there is no documentation.

Comment: I guess, your reps are enough for you to know what is expected as a good/valid question on SO.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

- Download the binaries either from Codeplex or Nuget.
- Add references to the binaries: `Elysium.Theme.dll`, `Microsoft.Expression.Interactions.dll`, `Microsoft.Windows.Shell.dll` and `System.Windows.Interactivity.dll`

  - Note: some of the binaries that come with the package aren't added correctly if you do it via Nuget so you'll have to add them manually.
- When you add a new window to your application, add this namespace to your XAML: `xmlns:metro="http://schemas.codeplex.com/elysium/theme"`
- Then change your XAML so that the window isn't just a `<Window ..>...</Window>` but is instead a `<metro:Window ..>...</metro:Window>`.
- There are lots of other examples in the test project on the Elysium site which show how to use the custom controls, etc.

That should get you started.

Best of luck.

Answer (score 3):

For Elysium 1.5 onwards, here's the step

- **Download** and **extract** zip file.
- Look for "**Elysium.dll**" and "**Elysium.Notifications.dll**". You might need to extract a zip again if you are using x86 system.
- Add **reference** to both Elysium.dll and Elysium.Notifications.dll
- Add Elysium theme controls at the visual studio **toolbox**
- **Drag and drop any Elysium theme control** to your user interface, visual studio will automatically add the xmlns reference in the xaml.

Refer http://bizvise.com/2012/09/24/how-to-install-elysium-on-visual-studio-project/ for a complete step by step guide.

Comment: Thanks JeeShen, that's a great info!

Answer (score 1):

Download SDK from [here](http://elysium.asvishnyakov.com/Downloads.cshtml#header) and intall the SDK. It integrates with Visual Studio and you have Metro WPF template as well.

Answer (score 1):

For Elysium Version 2.0, here's what I did:

1. Download the [SDK here](http://elysium.asvishnyakov.com/en/).
2. Extract the **.zip** file.
3. Install the correct **.exe** file (x86 or x64).
4. Restart your Visual Studio (if opened).
5. Create a new project with WPF Metro application:
   [image]
6. Finally, you can add the controls manually on your toolbar:
   [image]

If you like this extension, then you can donate on their website.