# How to use Elysium theme in wpf project

Tags: wpf, themes

I am  trying to use elysium theme I added it through Nuget also added the libraries manually but still not working , I cannot find and documentation.

Comment: Please provide some more details. What exactly is not working? What errors do you get? See also: [How to ask a question?](http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step by Step Guide to install Elysium - http://bizvise.com/2012/09/24/how-to-install-elysium-on-visual-studio-project/

Similar question answered here - [How do I use the Elysium Project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11704835/how-do-i-use-the-elysium-project)

Answer (score 0):

You can download documentation from [official site](http://elysiumproject.net).